# return all the posts where author.username equals $username

Tags: laravel

I have a posts model that has this relationship to the User:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

i am building a search function and I have this code

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->search;
    $filter = $request->filter;

    $append = array();

    $posts = Post::with('author')->with('categories')->latest();

    if($search){
        switch ($filter) {
            case 'username':
                $posts->author->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $search . '%');
            break;
        }
        $append += array('search' => $search);
        $append += array('filter' => $filter);
    }

    $posts = $posts->paginate(3);
    $posts->appends($append);

    return view('core.blog.posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

I get

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$author

How do I add where that looks for author based on his username? I must be able to add this condition in an if case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `whereHas()` to [searched based on a relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations). This will return only posts that have an author with the username.

```
switch ($filter) {
    case 'username':
        $posts->whereHas('author', function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $search . '%');
        });
    break;
}
```

Comment: thank you, your solution is perfect since I did not want to modify this line: $posts = Post::with('author')->with('categories')->latest(); as the other answer did.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If you need conditional where, you can do this:

```
$postSelector = Post::with('categories');
if($search){
switch ($filter) {
    case 'username':
        $postSelector->with(['author' => function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $search . '%');
        }]);
    break;
}

$posts = $postSelector->get();
```

Comment: I did and then same error but it complains about non existing method

Comment: I get Undefined variable: search, how do I pass search variable to a closure?

Comment: ok by using use($search) I solved this. However I get back all the posts from database, even belonging to other users

Comment: @maxit That is because this code will apply to the query to get the authors, not the query to get the posts. You want to use 'whereHas' to query posts that have a specific author.